# Wood Information Podium/Lectern Footing Re-build using Concrete and Post Bases

Tags: concrete, installation, post, footings

I am working on charity project for a local historical site. They have information signs that are on 6x6 wood that of course is rotting since they were set into the ground. The plan is to keep the signs but replace the 6x6 posts (about 3 feet high) with new ones and pour a concrete footing. The plan is to use the following:

1. Sakrete for the footing. I'm not sure how deep and wide to go since it's a small, light-load bearing post.
2. Metal standoff post base. Could I get away with an in-concrete post base and install it during the pour? I see that they're not used for free-standing objects like the information post, but since it's a light load and won't be subject to a lot of twisting, I thought I could try it. We're on tight budget and have to replace over 10 of them, so keeping costs down but doing the job right so it lasts is what we all want to deliver.

Any advice, information or recommendations would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: A podium is what you stand on so people can see you. A lectern is what you stand behind so it can hold your notes and microphone and such.

Comment: And it seems that this is asking about neither of them...

Comment: You need a post base with some moment strength, indicating that it resists pushover. Include the word "moment" with your post base search to find products that can resist wind, kids, etc.

Comment: It is the wind hitting the signs that can cause problems, not the weight.  If the old wood posts just plain wood then rot is expected.  Using ceder or pressure treated wood will extend the lifetime of the posts.  Posts and/or cement need to be placed below the local frost line.

Answer (score 2):

Use pressure treated posts embedded in concrete. It will be far cheaper than a post base designed to resist pushover, and they'll last decades if installed correctly. Microbe activity in the top 6" of soil typically causes the failure of ground contact posts, so embedding in concrete will solve the rot problem if the concrete extends above ground (don't hide the concrete under a layer of soil). Slope the concrete to shed water away from the post. To make the concrete above ground look nice, use some kind of form for the top 6" or so. I chopped up an old bucket with a reciprocating saw last time I did posts (Sonotube material is too expensive for a 6" tall form). A square form constructed from a 2x8 and some nails would work nice too (make an end or two longer than the box side so that you can take a good swing on it with a hammer to remove the form).